# map gradient to number value

Tags: javascript, gradient

I need to draw a gradient on a div/canvas or something. The gradient will start on one color and end on another. So only two colors(and the ones made up between). Lets say it starts on white and ends on black.

The application im working on calls an API that retturns a number betwenen 1-100.
The width of the gradient should be 100% i think to make the math "easy".

The number i get from the API should map to a position and hex code in the gradient and return those two.

How would i do something like that? Any ideas or code?

Comment: That doesn't really sound easy, and you're going to have to be more specific, how would one convert a number to a hex color, and what hex color etc ?

Comment: I know. I feel that it could be really hard. So basically the app receives a number between 1-100. depending on the value i marker gets set on the gradient. If the number is 12 the marker gets positioned left:12%; on the gradient-div. I need to know what color the gradient has at that specific position. (12% from left). the gradient goes from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand this correctly, you have:

```
startColor at 0%
endColor at 100%
chosenColor at x%
```

Lets assume you saved the hex colors like this (here white is the startColor):

```
startColor.red = 255;
startColor.green = 255;
startColor.blue = 255;
```

You calculate the difference in the two colors:

```
diffColor.red = endColor.red - startColor.red;
diffColor.green = endColor.green - startColor.green;
diffColor.blue = endColor.blue - startColor.blue;
```

Then you add the difference to the startColor, according to your x value:

```
markerColor.red = startColor.red + diffColor.red * x / 100;
markerColor.green = startColor.green + diffColor.green * x / 100;
markerColor.blue = startColor.blue + diffColor.blue * x / 100;
```

If you need to calculate the position it goes the same way:

```
markerPosition = startPosition + distance / x * 100
```

I have no idea if this is what you're looking for. I can't tell if your question is super complicated or really simple.